# Table in R with several row groups & sub-summation

Tags: r, finance, gt

I need to make a balance sheet table and group (and sum) its values according to not one, but several categories simultaneously. ((Random) sample data at the end).

TL;DR: How can I make "pretty" tables with sub-groups and "sub-summation"?

### What I have / can do

Using the `gt()` package I can easily sum for *one* category:

```
library(gt)
erg2 %>% gt(groupname_col = c("Kat_1")) %>%
  summary_rows(groups = TRUE,
               columns = 'Value',
               fns = list(Summe="sum")
  )
```

[image: OK]

This looks good. However, I need to sum for several categories (which gt can do) but it stops looking good (for my needs).

I dislike that the order is not OK (Starts with B. Current Assets, C. Liabilities appears 2x instead of being grouped together).

```
erg2 %>% gt(groupname_col = c("Kat_1","Kat_2","Kat_3")) %>%
  summary_rows(groups = TRUE,
               columns = 'Value',
               fns = list(Summe="sum")
  )
```

[image: notok]

### What I want

I would like to have the table *look* as follows (I'll try to draw it here as an example). It is ok (and desired) to have some of the aggregation sums appear several times. I am especially keen on the slight indentation of the different categories and that they build "sub-groups".

```
B. Current Assets
----------------------------------------
       Assets
----------------------------------------
         IV. Cash on Hand
----------------------------------------
               2. Current bank accounts
                           1000_Description_1   111
total sum current bank accounts                 111
total sum cash on hand                          111
 ...etc...
--------------------------------------------
          II. Receivables[..]
--------------------------------------------
               4. other assets
                          Account x     95
                          Account y     59
                          Account z     77
                    [...]
Sum 4. other assets                     [its sum]
...etc...
```

I am not limited to using `gt` - any package / procedure than can solve the problem is welcome. However aggregation and summation should be automated as much as possible.
It would be great to be able to embbed the final result in an RMarkdown.

### Example Data to play with:

```
erg2<-structure(list(main = c("Assets", "Equity & Liabilities", "Equity & Liabilities", 
"Equity & Liabilities", "Equity & Liabilities", "Equity & Liabilities", 
"Assets", "Assets", "Assets", "Assets", "Assets", "Assets", "Assets", 
"Assets", "Assets", "Assets", "Assets", "Assets", "Equity & Liabilities", 
"Equity & Liabilities", "Equity & Liabilities", "Equity & Liabilities", 
"Equity & Liabilities", "Equity & Liabilities", "Equity & Liabilities"
), Kat_1 = c("B. Current Assets", "C. Liabilites", "A. Equity", 
"C. Liabilites", "C. Liabilites", "C. Liabilites", "A. Fixed Assets", 
"A. Fixed Assets", "A. Fixed Assets", "A. Fixed Assets", "A. Fixed Assets", 
"A. Fixed Assets", "B. Current Assets", "B. Current Assets", 
"B. Current Assets", "B. Current Assets", "B. Current Assets", 
"C. Prepaid Expenses", "A. Equity", "A. Equity", "B. Accruals", 
"E. Deferred Taxes", "B. Accruals", "C. Liabilites", "C. Liabilites"
), Kat_2 = c("IV. Cash on hand, bank balances", "No category", 
"V. Profit / Loss of the year", "No category", "No category", 
"No category", "I. Intangible Assets", "I. Intangible Assets", 
"II. Tangible Assets", "II. Tangible Assets", "II. Tangible Assets", 
"II. Tangible Assets", "II. Receivables and other assets", "II. Receivables and other assets", 
"II. Receivables and other assets", "II. Receivables and other assets", 
"II. Receivables and other assets", "No category", "I. Subscribed capital", 
"IV. Profit / Loss carried forward", "No category", "No category", 
"No category", "No category", "No category"), Kat_3 = c("2. Current bank accounts", 
"3. Trade payables", "No category", "6. Other liabilities", "6. Other liabilities", 
"6. Other liabilities", "1. Franchises", "1. Franchises", "3. Other equipment", 
"3. Other equipment", "3. Other equipment", "3. Other equipment", 
"2. Receivables from affiliated companies", "4. Other assets", 
"4. Other assets", "4. Other assets", "4. Other assets", "No category", 
"No category", "No category", "1. Tax accruals", "No category", 
"2. Other accruals", "6. Other liabilities", "6. Other liabilities"
), `Acc-Nr` = c("1000_Description_1", "2000_Description_2", "3000_Description_3", 
"4000_Description_4", "5000_Description_5", "6000_Description_6", 
"7000_Description_7", "8000_Description_8", "9000_Description_9", 
"10000_Description_10", "11000_Description_11", "12000_Description_12", 
"13000_Description_13", "14000_Description_14", "15000_Description_15", 
"16000_Description_16", "17000_Description_17", "18000_Description_18", 
"19000_Description_19", "20000_Description_20", "21000_Description_21", 
"22000_Description_22", "23000_Description_23", "24000_Description_24", 
"25000_Description_25"), Value = c(111, 95, 78, 86, 87, 103, 
100, 114, 93, 137, 94, 91, 125, 95, 59, 77, 85, 98, 90, 115, 
59, 104, 110, 89, 75)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```